# nodejs - How to read and output jpg image?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I've been trying to find an example of how to read a jpeg image and then show the image.

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

fs.readFile('image.jpg', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.write(data);
});

res.end();
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Tried the following code but I think the encoding needs to be set as buffer. Using console.log it outputs 'Object' for the data.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Here is how you can read the entire file contents, and if done successfully, start a webserver which displays the JPG image in response to every request:

```javascript
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err // Fail if the file can't be read.
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'})
    res.end(data) // Send the file data to the browser.
  }).listen(8124)
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8124/')
})
```

Note that the server is launched by the "readFile" callback function and the response header has `Content-Type: image/jpeg`.

**[Edit]** You could even embed the image in an HTML page directly by using an `<img>` with a [data URI source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). For example:

```javascript
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
  res.write(Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'));
  res.end('"/></body></html>');
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it so lets say we read the jpeg data and put in the src attribute maybe through encoding it to base64?

Comment: Awesome! Just the solution I needed. Thanks for that second example.

Comment: what about if we have multiple images ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to keep in mind **Content-Type** and the **Encoding**

1) What if the file is css

```
if (/.(css)$/.test(path)) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'}); 
  res.write(data, 'utf8');
}
```

2) What if the file is jpg/png

```
if (/.(jpg)$/.test(path)) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'});
  res.end(data,'Base64');
}
```

Above one is just a sample code to explain the answer and not the exact code pattern.