# Sending two objects as response to a single GET request using Express and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, response

I have the following piece of code -

```
sendServer.get('/download',function(request,response){
var status="SELECT * from poetserver.download where status='0'";
console.log(status)
connection.query(status,function(error,rows){
    var toSend=rows[0].id
    response.sendfile('./testimages/'+toSend+'.PNG')
    // var details={"pictureId":toSend}
    // response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    // response.send(JSON.stringify(details));
```

Essentially I, first, want to send a file as identified by toSend. The file is successfully sent using response.sendFile. But I also want to provide some identification of the file for the client for future responses. How do I send that too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nodejs: How return different content types with same response (text and image)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886161/nodejs-how-return-different-content-types-with-same-response-text-and-image)

Comment: you should include it in the url/uri. That's what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

To send an id for the image (ressource) that you are responding with, you should use a [HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header) such as [`ETag`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). Do not try to send JSON and binary data in one response body.