# Get Image on page load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an HTML file with:

```
<img src="(Image from file)" alt="Raised Image" class="img-raised rounded img-fluid">
```

and I'm trying to get the image from file when the page loads, from the server.js file.

I'm using a node.js server with:

```
var express = require("express");

var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var image = "image.jpg";

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});


app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

How would one do this?

Comment: Why not just use a standard static file path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs - How to read and output jpg image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540978/nodejs-how-to-read-and-output-jpg-image)

Comment: What does this have to do with node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a directory which will be exposed to the public through the server. In below example, I have created a directory named `public` and provision it as a static folder to express to get all files from that folder.

Also, I made `dist` directory which will hold whole website artifacts. Artifacts are the files that are the result of the Build process of the website. I put `index.html` in the `dist` directory and provisioned the directory as a static folder to express to get all website related files from that folder.

Now, below is the code which will host a website and all public images file on root level (Also find whole solutions [here](https://repl.it/@siddharthmishra/ExpressJsStaticExample?language=nodejs).):

```
const express = require("express");
const Path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Create public folder and put all your images there.
const publicDirPath = Path.join(__dirname, 'public');

// Create a dist folder where all website artifacts will reside.
const distDirPath = Path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

// Make that public folder as static location for server.
app.use(express.static(publicDirPath));

// Root folder as a static folder
app.use(express.static(distDirPath));

// Now hitting `http://localhost:3000` will render index.html.
// and hitting `http://localhost:3000/image.png` will give you image.
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect('/');
  next();
});


app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```