# Simple way to import image from desktop into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, rest

I am trying to figure out how to import an image from my desktop into a .js file.

```
var express=require("express");

var http=require("http");

var app=express();
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('foo');

img.onload = function() {
    div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = C:\Users\image location

http.createServer(app).listen(11111);

console.log('Express server listening on port 11111');
```

Comment: Please fix syntax errors & formatting. Then make sure you understand the difference between a client (`document.getElementByID`) and a server ([read on](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web))

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up client side and server side code. Express only works on the server side, while document.getElementById only works on the client side (browser)

Comment: See the link https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: You refer to this article as well https://dzone.com/articles/upload-files-or-images-to-server-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Use node's built-in file system module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Example given on [W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp):

```
fs.readFile('picture.jpg', function(err, data) {
    ...
    ...
});
```

As far as your code, DOM-manipulating js should not be in server-side code. For instance:

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
```

This should be moved to a client-side file.

[See this Stack Overflow answer about importing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540978/nodejs-how-to-read-and-output-jpg-image).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all this code is server side so you cannot use the function `document.getElementById`. Now if you want to send an image to a client when they request to a specific endpoint, that can be done fairly easily.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.get('/sendImage', (req, res) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/image.jpeg');
    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

On the client side you can show image like this

```
<img src='localhost:11111/sendImage' />
```