# How can I fetch resized image from local folder to server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, sharp

Here is my server code. I want to show the resized images from the output folder, And here resize is a custom js created by me just to take image parameters and resize it. After resizing I want to show the image from the output folder.

[image: Folder Structure]

```
const express = require('express');
const files = require('fs');
const resize = require('./resize.js');

const server = express();
const port = 200;
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const PicName = req.query.name;
  const widthString = req.query.width;
  const heightString = req.query.height;
  const PicFormat = req.query.format;
  let width;
  let height;
  if (widthString) {
    width = parseInt(widthString);
    if (width < 1) {
      res.send('<h1>Error in parameter</h1>');
      return;
    }
  }
  if (heightString) {
    height = parseInt(heightString);
    if (height < 1) {
      res.send('<h1>Error in parameter</h1>');
      return;
    }
  }
  if (PicFormat === 'gif') {
    res.send('<h1>Error in format</h1>');
    return;
  }
  files.access(`./images/${PicName}`, files.constants.F_OK, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send('<h1>Image does not Exist</h1>');
      return;
    }
    res.type(`image/${PicFormat || 'jpg'}`);

    resize(`./images/${PicName}`, PicFormat, width, height).toFile(
      `./output/${PicName}`
    );
    resize(`./images/${PicName}`, PicFormat, width, height).pipe(res);
  });
});
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs - How to read and output jpg image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540978/nodejs-how-to-read-and-output-jpg-image)

Comment: What i wanted to know is in my code
resize(`./images/${PicName}`, PicFormat, width, height).toFile(
      `./output/${PicName}`
    );
    resize(`./images/${PicName}`, PicFormat, width, height).pipe(res);
  });
I have to do the resizing repeatedly to show the image. I want to do is resize once and show the image from the resized image folder to the localhost